# what c++ pointers do in this code

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f(int k[0]){ --k[1]; }
void g(int *k){(*(--k))++;}
void h(int k[1]){--k;}

int main(){
    int k[]={1,2,3,4};
    f(k+2);
    g(k+2);
    h(k+2);
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        cout << k[i];
}
```

Correct output is `333` but I thought it was `334`.
I do not understand what exactly happen in function f with the instruction  `--k[1]`. I could agree with the correct output if the code was `k[0]--`. What's the difference?
Thanks

Comment: Printing `k[4]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: He never prints k[4]

Comment: It doesn't matter what that code does because the _first_ thing you should do upon seeing it is track down the author and beat them until they cry like a baby. Then you should make them recode it in the manner a professional developer would, rather than a deranged monkey on amphetamines.

Comment: @paxdiablo I would assume that this is a quiz to test knowledge of C, and not production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--k[1]` decrements the value at `k[1]`, and given `f(k+2)` means the `f()`-local `k` points to the caller's (i.e. `main()`'s) `k[2]`, and the 1 and 2 indices add, you're actually decrementing the caller's `k[3]` from 4 to 3.

`k[0]--` would decrement the variable at `*k`, which for `f` would be known as `k[2]` in the caller's context.

The important insights for understanding this code are:

- all the functions `f`, `g` and `h` ultimately get a pointer to an `int`, and their notion of "`k`" is completely independent of the caller's notion of `k`, specifically - it's offset 2 `int`s further into the caller's `k` array,
- [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence): specifically, prefix decrement is applied *after* array subscripting in `--k[1]`.

That said, paxdiablo certainly has a point... ;-).

Comment: so it is different to write: `cout << (--k[1])`: it first dectrements the element in position 1 and then prints it; and : `cout << (k[1]--)`: it first prints the original value in position 1 and then decrease it. Right?

Comment: @bogALT: there is no `System.out.print` in C++, but if you used `std::cout <<` instead then yes - your statements are true in effect; being nit-picky, the second statement *copies* the value, decrements it, then prints the copy.

Comment: You're right, the exam has some exercises in Java and some in c++, so I mixed it. sorry

Comment: @bogALT No.  (Or at least not in C++ or C.)  `--k[i]` has the value of `k[i]`, decremented, and `k[i]--` has the value of `k[i]` before decrementation.  Both have the side effect of decrementing `k[i]`, some time after any preceding sequence point and before any following sequence point.  Since a function call is a sequence point, the decrementation must take place before it, in both cases.

Comment: I got it, thank you, so in both cases I'll get the same result from `cout`, correct?

Comment: @bogALT: not correct... `--k[1]` would be decremented first then printed, but `k[1]--` is copied, then decremented, then the copy printed, so it prints one more.  For example, if `k[1]` is say 5 before that line, then `cout << --k[1]` prints 4, but `cout << k[1]--` prints 5.

Comment: Ok, but in both cases i'll have 4 in `k[1]` (in the end), no?

Answer (score 1):

First, all three functions have exactly the same signature.  It would be less confusing if it had been written:

```
void f(int* pi){ --pi[1]; }
void g(int* pi){(*(--pi))++;}
void h(int* pi){--pi;}
```

(I've changed the name of the argument to avoid ambiguity in the following discutions.)

Also, of course: `a[b]` is, by definition, `*(a + b)`, and that any operation on `k` will convert it from `int[4]` to `int*`, pointing to the first element.

So we get the following results:

```
f( k + 2 );
//  In f, pi is k + 2, so `pi[1]` is *(k + 3).
//  After f, k = { 1, 2, 3, 3 }
g( k + 2 );
//  In g, pi starts out as k + 2; it is then decrementd to give k + 1
//  After g, k = { 1, 3, 3, 3 }
h( k + 2 );
//  In h, pi is k + 2.  A local copy of k + 2, so h doesn't change
//  k at all.
```

The results are that `k` is `{ 1, 3, 3, 3 }` after the four operations.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight change to the code, you can *see* what each step is doing:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *globk;
void dumpk(int *pk) {
    cout << "Array:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cout << ' ' << globk[i];
    cout << ", k at index " << (pk-globk) << '\n';
}

void f(int k[0]) { dumpk(k);    --k[1];  dumpk(k); }
void g(int *k)   { dumpk(k); (*(--k))++; dumpk(k); }
void h(int k[1]) { dumpk(k);    --k;     dumpk(k); }

int main(){
    int k[]={1,2,3,4};
    globk = k;  // save for detecting where k is

    f(k+2);
    g(k+2);
    h(k+2);

    // slightly prettier output.

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        cout << k[i] << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

The output of that shows what each step does:

```
Array: 1 2 3 4, k at index 2
Array: 1 2 3 3, k at index 2
--k[1];         // -- array VALUE at INDEX 3 (2+1) down to 3

Array: 1 2 3 3, k at index 2
Array: 1 3 3 3, k at index 1
(*(--k))++;     // -- POINTER to [1], then ++ that VALUE up to 3

Array: 1 3 3 3, k at index 2
Array: 1 3 3 3, k at index 1
--k;            // Simply -- POINTER with no change to any VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

What this code is doing is:

1. Pass a an array starting at the 3rd element in `k[]` to `f`. `f` takes a 1-dimensional array and decreases its 2nd element (in this case it will be `k[4]` which will change its value of 4 to 3).
2. Pass a pointer of the 3rd element in `k[]` to `g`. `g` takes a pointer to an integer or array, and first decreases the value of the pointer (becoming now a pointer to the 2nd element of `k[]`) and then increases the value of what's pointed, changing it from 2 to 3.
3. Pass a an array starting at the 3rd element in `k[]` to `h`. ``h receives a 1-dimensional array and decreases the pointer to the array (not the value it points to) thus not modifying the values of the pointed array.

Comment: `f` doesn't take a one dimensional array; it takes a pointer.  Same thing for `h`.

Answer (score 0):

f and g are modifying values, while h is modifying an address:

```
f(int k[0]){ --k[1]; }
```

f take one parameter, an array of int; k[1] is the same as k++ in this case; the function is decrementing the value of the element situated at the next address vs the one passes as argument. So It's decrementing k[3] in your main.

g is relatively straight forward and I think you figured that out.

h is similar to f

```
h(int k[1]){--k;}
```

h takes a int array as input and it decrements the address passed as argument.

Hope this helps